# Run python script from html button submit

Tags: python

i have a code input data to txt file :

```
<form action="proses.php" method="post">
    Nomor Polisi : <br><input type="text" name="nopol"><br>
    <input type="submit" id ="submitButton" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and i have a python script on this path :

```
/home/pi/folder/folder1/test.py
```

i try python script run with command line work fine. The problem is, how i can run python script test.py from html form code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In `proses.php`, you can call your command using [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

```
shell_exec ("python /home/pi/folder/folder1/test.py")
```

Warning ! Most free  hosting services disabled the use of `shell_exec` PHP function for security reasons.

Comment: Any easy example or code? My code to run script python for thermal printer.

Comment: I don't know what example code I can provide. shell_exec run a command or script like any you can run from your shell...

Comment: ok. the point is, how i can run python script with html button to print value from txt file used epson TM T82.

Comment: Sorry, this is another question. In addition, I can't help you with so few information. Please create a new post to ask this question.